# My computer is 32 Bit Windows XP ,I downloaded Ubuntu12.04LTS -64 bit

Tags: 12.04

I have Windows XP -as per process it is 32 bit,I used wubi and downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 2 days ago-in details it shows 64 bit..It is working on my PC but I find small font for all I do on website.
Is this because 64 bit is downloaded on 32 bit?Pl guide and suggest way out.
I have elementary knowledge of computers.Should I uninstal 64 bits and have 32 bit ?
Pl give advice,thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! @user261146: If hmayag's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

If your processor was 32bit, you wouldn't be able to run 12.04LTS-64bit. You are running it, so that's your answer.

As far as font size is concerned, it has nothing to do with bits. To increase the size when viewing a web page, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. To decrease size, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. If your mouse has a wheel, you can increase size by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Wheel-up</kbd>.

To download the 32bit version, go to the official [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and select the desired version from the drop-down menu.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! The font size tip did help me.
I do not know whether 12.04. LTS has 32 bit version also !